# Menu item not being rendered properly

Tags: windows, gui, rendering

I've got an odd issue with a proprietary piece of software I'm managing for a client (host, backup, update, etc).

Basically, the problem is that one of the menu items only displays half way. It's present on the same item at that height on most, but not all, of the other menus from the bar.

Any ideas on what normally causes this issue with a Windows application ? I've tried changing screen resolution, DPI, system theme, menu animation, ClearType, etc.

This a screen shot to show what I'm talking about.

[image: Screenshot of menu problem]

It's a fairly common (in the specialty it is for) program, running on Windows 2k3 with all updates. I've been going back and forth with the vendor, but haven't had any luck so far.

Comment: Does the code have a handler for the Windows message that queries for a menu item height?

Comment: @Stacey No idea, I'm not involved in the development of this program.

Comment: Is that the only menu entry that does it?  What are the system locale/language settings set to?  (Perhaps the menu item has a weird character that doesn't agree with your language settings?)

Comment: @technie I reset the location to English(US) from English(Somewhere else) with no luck. Thanks for the tip though.